# What is turning ON my Android Screen?

Tags: android, screen, adb

My Android phone's Screen turns ON automatically in random even when it is locked.

I need to know which app is causing this trouble.

Is there any **adb** commands to check which app had turned the screen ON recently?

**Phone:** ASUS Zenfone 5

**OS:** Android Lollipop

More specifically, I am interested in finding

1. SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK
2. SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
3. FULL_WAKE_LOCK

Answer (score 0):

When an Android app registers a broadcast receiver, it keeps listening for events (wifi detected, low battery, server push) even if the app has stopped and the screen is locked.

When the event is triggered, the app is automatically launched.

To find which app is in cause, take a look at the **Application Manager** which shows currently running apps. The timestamp indicates the launching hour. The last one is the owner of the receiver...

http://www.wikihow.com/See-What-Apps-Are-Currently-Running-on-Android